# Nginx reverse proxy to two services

Tags: nginx

I'm running nodeJS script..

- on `localhost:9001`
- it is running behind nginx reverse proxy
- it accept request in the form of `/v{{ version }}/{{ lang }}/...`

So for example:

- `domain.com/api/v1/en/news`
- `domain.com/api/v2/fr/news`
- `domain.com/api/v3/en/news`

Until now I had this is nginx

```
  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:9001/;
  }
```

and everything work.

My goal now is to run additional (identical) script on `localhost:9002` which will accept `v4` requests. And `v3`, `v2` and `v1` will be still 'processed' by `localhost:9001`

So I want that request `domain.com/api/v4/en/news` is routed to `localhost:9002`

I put this **above** current rule like this

```
location ~* /api/v4/(.*)$ {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:9002/v4/$1;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:9001/;
  }
```

Request `/v3/..` is routed to `localhost:9001` (as expected) but `/v4/..` returns `502`.

Any pointers?

Comment: 500 - is not 502. it means Your app which runs at 9001 port is crashing, check app logs

Comment: Sorry about that, I get `502` not `500`

Comment: `apt-get install lsof`  then `lsof -i :9002`  what You see?

Comment: also no need for regular expression. it's just a mapping. so fix location: `location /api/v4/ {`  and `proxy_pass         http://localhost:9002/v4/;`

Comment: that worked! if you want you can write it as a answer so that I can mark it

Comment: I don't insist for upvote. put Your answer and I'll upvote it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
location /api/v4/ {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:9002/v4/;
}

location /api/ {
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:9001/;
}
```